# spring mvc http proxy

Tags: spring-mvc, proxy, forward, basic-authentication

I would like to write a spring MVC Controller class that just take any http request in input, add basic authentication headers to it and forward this request to another server.
I try something like this without success.

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/proxyws")
    public class ProxyController {

    @RequestMapping("/**")
    @ResponseBody
    public String mirrorRest( @RequestBody String body, HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws URISyntaxException
    {

        String server = "localhost";
        int port = 8080;
        URI uri = new URI("http", null, server, port, request.getRequestURI(), request.getQueryString(), null);
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<String>(body);
        String plainCreds = "APP_CLIENT:APP_PASSWORD"; 
        byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
        byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
        String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
        entity.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, method, entity, String.class);

        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
```

For a GET method in input, I get the following exception : 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required     request body content is missing:

```
org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter@8051792a
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleEmptyBody(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:170)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:105)
```

For a POST request, I get other trouble with le basic auth headers:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Collections.java:1342)
at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.java:831)
```

Thanx for your help!

Comment: Although I am sure you can get this to work with some hacking (probably will have to separate GET and POST methods for starters), and although I love Spring MVC, the use case you presented (simply adding Basic Auth to the request ) is very unfit for an MVC framework. You can accomplish this task in an easier and much more performant using Nginx. Check out [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/230749/how-to-use-nginx-to-proxy-to-a-host-requiring-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the headers of the `HttpEntity` object once it's instantiated. You need to pass your headers in through a different `HttpEntity` constructor, e.g.

```
public HttpEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String, String> headers) {
    this.body = body;
    HttpHeaders tempHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    if (headers != null) {
        tempHeaders.putAll(headers);
    }
    this.headers = HttpHeaders.readOnlyHttpHeaders(tempHeaders);
}
```

Note the initialization of `this.headers`: that's where the read-only copy is created.